# Regex syntax with quotes

Tags: c#, regex, syntax

I'm trying to run a regex string in my code that will pick up everything that is between `<li class="f"` and `</li>`

```
string regex = @"\<li\sclass="f"(\s*?.*?)*?\</li>";
```

But the syntax is wrong because of the quotes. I tried replacing them with just `'`
but it didn't find anything.

The regex string is working by-the-way it's just these quotes that are not. I was trying to look after some replacement like space-->/s and didn't find anything.

Comment: I afraid this is not much related to RegEx, because it's simply a C# problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To escape the quotes in a string, double them:

```
string regex = @"<li\sclass=""f""(.*?)</li>";
```

I've also "fixed" your regex a bit, but it's still not a good idea to be using a regex for parsing HTML.

Answer (score 0):

use shield symbols

`@""""; //"`

`"\""; //"`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't escaped your quotes, but shouldn't be using regular expressions to parse HTML anyway. Use something like the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), and then code along these lines;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load("file.htm");

    var results = doc.DocumentNode
        .SelectNodes("//li[contains(@class, 'f')]")
        .Select(x => x.InnerHtml);

    foreach (string result in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```